# Is every Heyting algebra a sublattice of a Boolean algebra?

Tags: boolean-algebra, lattice-orders, heyting-algebra

From what I can tell, every lattice is a sublattice of a lattice with unique complements (Dilworth). A Heyting algebra is a distributive lattice. The only remaining step, then, would be to know whether the extension with unique complements preserves distributivity. If that is true, then every Heyting algebra would be a sublattice of a distributive complemented lattice, a Boolean algebra.

Comment: What precise definition of "sublattice" are you using?  I would think that the theorem of Dilworth you refer to uses a weak definition where $0$ and $1$ do not have to be preserved (otherwise it certainly cannot be correct).  So if you want your sublattices to preserve $0$ and $1$, that theorem would seem irrelevant.

Comment: @EricWofsey Given the answer below, it may as well be...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Every distributive lattice is isomorphic to a lattice of sets, so in particular it is a sublattice of a Boolean algebra.  Since Heyting algebras are distributive lattices, the answer to your question is affirmative.

Answer (score -1):

Heyting Algebra is not a sublattice for Boolean Algebra.since Heyting Algebra weakens x\vee x'. Boolean Algebra is asublattice for Heyting Algebra.

Comment: I didn't downvote your answer, but I must warn you that it is wrong. Every Heating algebra is a sub-lattice of a Boolean algebra, in the sense that the lattice reduct of the HA is a sub-lattice of the lattice reduct of the BA, as Andreas Blass explains in his answer. It is also true, in a very trivial way, that every BA is a sub-lattice of a HA: given a BA, just append it a new top element.